# recreate basic specular highlight with shader

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, toon-shading

I'm trying to create a non photorealistic rendering shader in eevee and i want to add a specular highlight.
i don't want to use the specular shader or a black principled shader because they also reflect the sky and all the lights i have. i only want one specified sun lamp to create this specular highlight.
so basically i think i have to recreate a simple formula like cook torr for specular highlights in blender nodes. anyone have an idea how to do that? any help would be appreciated :)
someone has already done this for point lights but i cant figure out how to do this for directional lights.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107390/67665

Comment: If you are open to do OSL shaders (scripts), you could check [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/where-are-lambert-of-phong-shaders-in-blender/1310118/32?u=l0lock). If you are ok with nodes spaghetti, I'd look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQdIxkd54X4). I don't think I have seen a shader that can take a specific lamp object as sole input (not without OSL or compiling your own Blender with a fully custom node). Maybe you can do that with layer though/

Comment: the thing you mentioned with node spaghetti is great, but it seems to only work for point lights with a specified position. i'm trying to do this with a sun light, using its direction as a vector somehow